# Need w3-include-html partial include

Tags: html, include

I´m using this W3 script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>

<body>

<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div> 

<script>
w3.includeHTML();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It works perfectly, but my issue would be that I only need one particular portion of the "content.html", and not all of it. So my question is: How do I use w3-include-html for PARTIALLY html include?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't include part of a partial; the whole **point** of a 'partial' is that it in itself represents **part** of the code, not code that you should extract a part **from**.

You can include more than one partial on a page, but the partials themselves must be exactly what you're trying to include at that point; you can't 'extract' content from a partial.

Simply shrink your `content.html` so that it only contains the output that you would like to include on your main page.

Having said that, considering W3.js can only import **HTML**, there's literally no reason to store the partial HTML in an external file. Not only does this create a second, unecessary file, but it also adds a reliance on JavaScript. If your visitor opts to disable their JavaScript, your partial won't work. Thus, I strongly recommend simply writing the content of `content.html` in the **main page** itself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!! The reason why I wanted just a portion of that content.html, is that it´s a shared html. So in one page, I just need a portion of it, but in the other, I need the whole content. html showing. BTW, do you know another partial include workaround that can help me with this problem? Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget that you can write additional HTML on the same page that you include `content.html` on. First, trim `content.html` to only contain the content that should be in **both** pages. Then simply write the additional HTML **directly** into the page that requires the HTML that you cut **out** of `content.html`. Then page A will contain the full HTML that was initially in `content.html`, while page B only contains what is in it **now** (part of what was it in it before). This gives you the same effect as simply including part of what was in the old `content.html` ;)